# Displacy from spacy in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy

I'm trying to run a displacy server in google colab:

```
from spacy import displacy

frasesin=nlp("Yo quisiera saber porqué el jugador hizo tan mala jugada")

dep=[]
for x in range(1,len(frasesin)):
    dep.append([ frasesin[x].text, frasesin[x].dep_, frasesin[x].head.text])

dep
displacy.serve(frasesin, style="dep")
```

And it is running fine:

```
Using the 'dep' visualizer
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:5000 ...
```

But how can I access this port in colab to see the results?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use displacy.render instead of .serve, and set jupyter=True

```
from spacy import displacy

displacy.render(doc, style='dep', jupyter=True, options={'distance': 90})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
Try this: http://localhost:5000/ 
It worked for me

Comment: You should Write comment instead of writing answer for one line solution.

Comment: thank for bringing this Roger but this is not the solution :-(

Comment: This could work if the notebook is running on local. But as of this question is about Colab Notebooks this is irrelevant